# How Entity Framework 6 decides if the FK should be defined with ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, entity-framework-6

I have a bunch of classes that are related to each other.

Let's take for example the following class hierarchy:

```
Class A
{
    // PK
    public string A_Id

    // Navigation Property
    public virtual ICollection<B> MyB{ get; set; }
}


Class B
{
    // PK
    public int B_Id

    // FK - On Delete - NO ACTION     <---------- Difference here
    public string A_Id { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual A MyA { get; set; }
    public List<C> MyC{ get; set; }
}

Class C
{
    // PK
    public int C_Id

    // FK - On Delete - CASCADE     <---------- Difference here
    public int B_Id { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual B MyB { get; set; }
}
```

When I check the FKs in **SQL Management Studio** I see that On delete cascade is defined on **Class C's FK**, but NOT on **Class B's FK**.

Also, when I try to delete an instance of A, I get different run-time exceptions because there are rows that reference that instance.

> Why is this happening?
>
> What should I do to define them both to On Delete Cascade?
>
> How EF6 determines how to define the FKs??

I've read many SO answers without success.

I also tried to define the FK using **Fluent API**, but it just created a second FK instead of modifying the first. =[

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after much struggling here is the correct answer:

Entity framework default behavior is "On Delete Cascade"

**But it can define "ON DELETE CASCADE" only when the column is Non-Nullable.**

So if we go back to the example, we can see that Class A has a **string** PK (**nullable**) and class B has an **int** PK (**non-nullable**). And that explains the difference.

How to solve it?

> The best solution is to set a **[Required]** attribute above the
>   FK property, otherwise, the EF6 engine will treat that property as
>   nullable and define On Delete -> No Action!

Working example:

```
Class A
{
    // PK
    public string A_Id

    // Navigation Property
    public virtual ICollection<B> MyB{ get; set; }
}


Class B
{
    // PK
    public int B_Id

    // FK - On Delete - NO ACTION     <---------- Difference here
    [Required]          <------------------------ SOLUTION =] =] =]
    public string A_Id { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual A MyA { get; set; }
    public List<C> MyC{ get; set; }
}

Class C
{
    // PK
    public int C_Id

    // FK - On Delete - CASCADE     <---------- Difference here
    public int B_Id { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual B MyB { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **DbContext** class you can get this done with FluentAPI like this:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
            .HasOptional(a => a.MyB)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
```

it gives you the flexibility to play with the non-required fields too.

Comment: Hi, I tried with FluentAPI (as i mentioned in my question). The problem that it created a second FK, which is not needed. Does your code creates a new FK? I used this: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @Yitzchak what do you mean by 'it created second FK'? help me understand

Comment: ok, now I understand, when you use code-first, you can set up your tables relationships by just keeping the correct naming conventions. If you want to name your properties not as EF expects, you should then create the relationships by using one of the following ways: 1. Use annotations (like the ForeignKey annotation) 2. Use Fluent Api. In my case I defined my keys with annotations, so when I’m ADDING Fluent Api code I get more FKs than needed. (From class B I have 2 FKs to class A’s ID)

Comment: Yes Exactly, the navigation property basically creates a Foreign key behind the scenes for you.

Comment: +1 for correct answer, your answer does appear in other SO posts, the purpose of my post is to understand EF behind the scenes so the developer can choose the best solution for him.

Comment: Thank You, +1 for your solution too.